# How to combine different kernels for Gaussian process in GPyTorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning-model, pytorch, gaussian-process

I am trying to learn gaussian process by using `GPyTorch` to fit a `Gaussian Process Regression` model. However, I can't figure out a way to combine different kernels as shown in `sklearn` implementation of gaussian process. I am using GPyTorch as it is more flexible and have lot more kernels that one can play with compared to `scikit-learn`. 
Any help, particularly with code snippet would be very useful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From official documentation: For example, to compose two kernels via addition, you can either add the kernel modules directly:

```
self.covar_module = ScaleKernel(RBFKernel() + WhiteNoiseKernel())
```

Or you can add the outputs of the kernel in the forward method:

```
covar_x = self.rbf_kernel_module(x) + self.white_noise_module(x)
```

The class for GPRegressionModel would then look like this:

```
class GPRegressionModel(gpytorch.models.ExactGP):
def __init__(self, train_x, train_y, likelihood):
    super(GPRegressionModel, self).__init__(train_x, train_y, likelihood)

    self.mean_module = gpytorch.means.ConstantMean()
    self.covar_module = ScaleKernel(RBFKernel() + WhiteNoiseKernel())

def forward(self, x):
    mean_x = self.mean_module(x)
    covar_x = self.covar_module(x)
    return gpytorch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(mean_x, covar_x)
```

Comment: are there any applied article which talks about the effect of these kernels and how to set them to achieve desired effect? Thanks

Comment: Applied not, but you maybe want to start with https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~duvenaud/cookbook/. There are also good suggestions on further reading.

Comment: Good suggestion. Rasmussen and Williams is very good but takes time to understand it and code them up.